# Can nflx:// app run within an IOS app using UIWebView

Tags: iphone

I am writing an IOS app where I would like to launch the Netflix app (nflx://) within my app using UIWebView.    I would like to have the Netfix movies run within my UIWebview structure so when the user stops the movie it will go back to my app control.

I have have done the following:

1). I can launch nflx:// within UIWebview and the app immediately launches by leaving my app.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"nflx://"];

NSURLRequest *requestPage = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
     loadingView = [LoadingView loadingViewInView:webPage];


self.webPage.delegate = self;
[self.webPage loadRequest: requestPage];
     [self.webPage setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

2). I have launched the Netflix website @"movies.netflix.com://.  This allows the user to select the video within my app, but once the video starts it exits to the Netflix app.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"@"movies.netflix.com://"];

NSURLRequest *requestPage = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
     loadingView = [LoadingView loadingViewInView:webPage];

self.webPage.delegate = self;
[self.webPage loadRequest: requestPage];
     [self.webPage setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

Is this possible?  If so any guidance would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you left your app by using an url scheme, there is no way to go back to your app, if the other application does not provide an API for you to provide your scheme or the user manually goes back.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I thought by going to netflix's website using UIWebView I would be able to stay within my app as I have done with YouTube, FB...  Seems like Netflix launches their own app therefore they leave my app.